# Custom Control does not save changes to property

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I'm using this DependencyProperty to store an collection of strings:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( nameof( ItemsSource ) , typeof( IEnumerable<string> ) , typeof( MyClass) , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( new List<string>() , FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault ) );
```

In the property of ItemsSource, I'm trying to filter out strings, that are chosen already. Like this

```
SetValue( ItemsSourceProperty , source.Except( target ).ToList() );
return (IEnumerable<string>) GetValue( ItemsSourceProperty );
```

source contains all the possible values, target the chosen values. source.Except( target ).ToList() works fine, but the result is never stored in the DependencyProperty.

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: In case you are binding the ItemsSource property (and with a couple of other so-called value sources), WPF bypasses the property setter and directly calls SetValue. That's why you must not call anything else than `SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value)` in the property setter. It's explained here: [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-loading-and-dependency-properties)

Comment: Besides that, you must not use `new List<string>()` as default value. All instances of your MyClass would operate on the same collection object.

Comment: Where is the best place for this line: source.Except( target ).ToList() ?

Comment: What is a usable default value for the ItemsSourceProperty?

Comment: If there is a Binding, set its Converter. The default value should be null.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea, what this particular Converter would have to look like. What is the convertion?

Comment: There's online documentation. See the Converter property of the Binding class (if you use a Binding - we still don't know).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am using a Binding. Here's the property of the custom control:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ItemsSource
{
    get
    {
        var source = (IEnumerable<string>) GetValue( ListBoxSourceProperty);
        var target = (IEnumerable<string>) GetValue( SelectedItemsProperty);


        if ( source == null )
        {
            source = (IEnumerable<string>) GetValue( ItemsSourceProperty );
            ListBoxSource = source;
        }


        if ( source.ToList().Count == 0 )
        {
            source = (IEnumerable<string>) GetValue( ItemsSourceProperty );
            ListBoxSource = source;
        }

        var tmp = source.Except( target ).ToList(); // tmp.Count() = 5

        SetValue( ItemsSourceProperty , tmp ); // nothing is written here

        var tmp2 =(IEnumerable<string>) GetValue( ItemsSourceProperty );  // tmp2.Count() = 6 !!!


        OnPropertyChanged( "ItemsSource" );
        return tmp;  // the control displays 6 elements every time
    }

    set
    {
        SetValue( ItemsSourceProperty , value );
    }
}
```

And this is property in DataContext

```
public ObservableCollection<string> ItemSource
{
    get
    {
        if ( _itemsSource == null )
        {
            _itemsSource = new ObservableCollection<string>( _catalog );
        }

        return _itemsSource;
    }
    set { /*_itemsSource = value;*/ }
}
```

_catalog and _itemSource are of type List

And finally the binding expression in the xaml file:

```
<local:MyControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource}" />
```